# Need to convert column to row format based on another column values

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
ABC 1
XYZ 1
QWE 1
GRE 1
DGD 2
GER 2
OUT 2
RTY 3
POI 3
MNB 3
LKJ 3
```

Expected output:

```
ABC XYZ QWE GRE
DGD GER OUT 
RTY POI MNB LKJ
```

ie., All words with the same second column value should appear in a same line separated by a single space.

Comment: please read [what should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk and printing the output records in the same order as they appear in the input and without reading all of the input into memory:

```
$ awk '
    $2 != prev { if (NR>1) print rec; rec=$1; prev=$2; next }
    { rec = rec OFS $1 }
    END { print rec }
' file
ABC XYZ QWE GRE
DGD GER OUT
RTY POI MNB LKJ
```

The above assumes your input is grouped by your 2nd field values as shown in your sample input, if that's not the case then just sort them first - `sort -k2,2 file | awk 'script'`

The above just stores the set of $1s for a $2 in memory as each $2 appears in the input, if you don't even want to do that you could just print the $1s as they appear:

```
$ awk '
    $2 != prev { if (NR>1) print ""; printf "%s", $1; prev=$2; next }
    { printf "%s%s", OFS, $1 }
    END { print "" }
' file
ABC XYZ QWE GRE
DGD GER OUT
RTY POI MNB LKJ
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk '{a[$2]=a[$2]" "$1} END {for (i in a) print substr(a[i],2)}'
```

The `substr` is used to remove leading space

Comment: Wouldn't the use of `OFS` be useful in more case ? And is it more efficient to use a `substr` at the end or would it be better to use a conditional when adding element to the array ?

Comment: @Marius_Couet, OFS IMHO is not applicable here because we concatenate strings, not print the tokens. `substr` at the end execute only number of times of resulting rows. If use if it will execute on every row from source file. And if you have (for example) millions of rows in source will slow down the execution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation for the `substr` part. But about the `OFS` part you can concatenate it. `a[$2]=a[$2]" "$1` can be replaced by `a[$2]=a[$2] OFS $1`, but in that case you'd need to replace the `substr` number with `length(OFS)+1` (for it to be applicable in any cases)

Comment: @Marius_Couet, yes, this can work. Also instead of `OFS` you can use any predefined variable in `awk`. But I personally prefer to have clear and sample code :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to process the header-less "pretty-printed" (whitespace-delimited) data:

```bash
$ mlr --pprint -N nest --ivar ' ' -f 1 then cut -f 1 file
ABC XYZ QWE GRE
DGD GER OUT
RTY POI MNB LKJ
```

This folds the entries from the first field using Miller's `nest` operation, grouped by the data in the second field.  The folded entries will be delimited by spaces (the character in single quotes on the command line).  The second operation, `cut`, extracts only the folded field.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` (actually `gawk` in my case):

```bash
 awk '{array[$2]=($2 in array ? array[$2]" " : "") $1} END{for (key in array) print array[key]}' data.txt
```

Or if you want to remove the *ternary operator* (`condition ? value : value`):

```bash
awk '{array[$2]=array[$2]" "$1} END{for (key in array) print array[key]}' data.txt
```

The difference between both `awk` commands is that the second one will print a **space** at the beginning of each line:

```
#First awk command:
ABC XYZ QWE GRE
DGD GER OUT
RTY POI MNB LKJ

#Second one:
 ABC XYZ QWE GRE
 DGD GER OUT
 RTY POI MNB LKJ
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -sW groupby 2 collapse 1 --collapse-delimiter ' ' <file | datamash cut 2
```

About collapse delimiter from its manual:

```
--collapse-delimiter=x
-c x
Use character X instead of comma to delimit items in a ‘collapse’ or ‘unique’ (aka ‘uniq’) list.
```